# How to save the user input data in a db in spring-boot

Tags: javascript, java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have created springboot application. I want to save the user entered data in db table "orders" (in postgresql)

I already created icecream.html file using thymeleaf. And i used script.js file to integrate.

IcecreamDao.java

```
@Repository
public class IcecreamDao {

    @Autowired 
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;  
    private static final String SQL2 = "INSERT INTO orders (id, name, price, qty, total, cname) VALUES (:id, :name ,:price, :qty, :total, :cname)"; 


    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    // To create new record
    public Icecream saveIcecream(Icecream icecream)  {

        KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

        SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("id", icecream.getid())
                .addValue("cname", icecream.getCName())
                .addValue("name", icecream.getName())
                .addValue("price", icecream.getPrice())
                .addValue("qty" , icecream.getQty())
                .addValue("total", icecream.getTotal());

                namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(SQL2, parameters, holder);
                icecream.setid(holder.getKey().intValue());
                return icecream;
}
}
```

IcecreamController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/") 
public class IcecreamController {
@Autowired 
    public IcecreamDao icecreamDao; 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", produces="application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody Icecream icecream, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) { 

        icecreamDao.saveIcecream(icecream);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(icecream.getid()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<List>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

script.js

```
function updateClick() {
      var icecream = {id:0 , name:"" , cname: "",  price: 0, qty: 0, total: 0 } 

      icecream.id = $("#id").val();
      icecream.cname = $("#cname").val();
      icecream.name = $("#name").val(); 
      icecream.price = $("#price").val();
      icecream.qty = $("#qty").val();
      icecream.total = $("#total").val();

      productAdd(icecream);
    }

function productAdd(icecream) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(icecream),
        success: function (icecream) 
        {
          productAddSuccess(icecream);
        },
        error: function (request, message, error) {
          handleException(request, message, error);
        }
      });
    }

function productAddSuccess(icecream) {
      productAddRow(icecream);
      formClear();
    }

function formClear() {
      $("#id").val("");
      $("#cname").val("");
      $("#name").val("");
      $("#price").val("");
      $("#qty").val("");
      $("#total").val("");
    }
function addClick() {
      formClear();
    }
```

icecream.html

```
<body>
    <form>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <h1> <u>Order Your Ice-cream</u> </h1>


            <label for="id">Order Id:</label>
            <input type="text" id="id" value="Please Enter Your order id    "> <br> <br> 

            <label for="cname">Customer Name :</label>
            <input type="text" id="cname" value="Please Enter Your Name"> <br> <br> 

            <label for="name">Ice-Cream Name :</label> <select id="name" onchange="pickicecream()">
                <option>Select Ice_Cream</option>
                <option>Vanilla Icecream</option>
                <option>Chocolate Icecream</option>
                <option>Blueberry Icecream</option>
                <option>CheeseCake with Waffle</option>
            </select> <br> <br> 

            <label for="price">Price :</label> 
            <input type="text" id="price" value="0"> <br> <br> 

            <label for="qty">Quantity :</label>

            <!-- Increment Button -->
            <div class="value-button" id="increase">+</div>
            <input type="number" id="qty" value="0" onclick="calTotal()" />
            <div class="value-button" id="decrease">-</div>

            <p> Total Amount : <input type="text" id="total" value="0"> </p>

            <button type="submit" id="saveButton" value="Submit" onclick="updateClick()">Submit</button> <br> <br>

            Click Here To See <a th:href="@{orders/view}">Your Orders </a> <br> <br>

        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

All the user entered data must save in my table "orders". but it's not saving. Please someone guide me about what went wrong in my code... Thanks in advance.

Comment: `namedParameterJdbcTemplate` is it initialised  ?

Comment: If you are using Spring Data you shouldn't write SQL-query. Just declare your DAO as repository interface:

    `public interface IcecreamDao implements Repository<Icecream, Long>`

and use `icecreamDao.save(icecream)`